# Jquery AJAX .error produces error "Cannot read property fieldErrors of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am building a simple Spring MVC application that functions as a library of DVDs. The problem occurs when attempting to validate fields in a form.

The AJAX call that creates the problem is here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add-button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'dvd',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        title: $('#add-title').val(),
        releaseDate: $('#add-releaseDate').val(),
        mpaaRating: $('#add-mpaaRating').val(),
        director: $('#add-director').val(),
        studio: $('#add-studio').val(),
        note: $('#add-note').val(),
        image: $('#add-image').val()
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      'dataType': 'json'
    }).success(function(data, status) {
      $('#add-title').val('');
      $('#add-releaseDate').val('');
      $('#add-mpaaRating').val('');
      $('#add-director').val('');
      $('#add-studio').val('');
      $('#add-note').val('');
      $('#add-image').val('/img/default.jpg');
      $('#validationErrors').empty();
    }).error(function(data, status) {
      $('#validationErrors').empty();
      $.each(data.responseJSON.fieldErrors, function(index, validationError) {
        var errorDiv = $("#validationErrors");
        errorDiv.append(validationError.message).append($("<br>"));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

One thing I noticed was that in a different project where the exact same code functions as intended, the response header shows a type of JSON. My code for this project produces a response header with type text.

The thing that really bugs me here is that the success function works just fine. So why doesn't error work?

I've looked at a bunch of different questions from other posters and have yet to come across a solution.

Comment: Your success function doesn't reference the response 'data' at all, but your error function does. That could possibly be why one fails but the other does not.

Comment: What does your response message look like, **exactly**.  Is it a JSON string or is it a bare String?

Comment: How would I got about getting the response message? Is that in Chrome developer tools somewhere? (My apologies for not knowing.)

Comment: If you are seeing the error block getting executed so you can safely assume that your ajax is failing. Check in MVC controller are you rightly handling the the params. Secondly from this line  $.each(data.responseJSON.fieldErrors, function(index, validationError) { I assume you are expecting an array of fieldErrors? Can you please simply do console.log(data) and check what it is printing?

Comment: console.log(data) within .error produces: 
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.…line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.27</h3></body></html>", status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request"}

And yeah, I am expecting an array of errors.

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value="/dvd", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    public Dvd createDvd(@Valid @RequestBody Dvd d){
        dao.createDvd(d);
        return d;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project, created all new files, copy and pasted the contents into the new files -> Clean and Build -> Deploy... it worked.

I made no changes to the underlying code. I just gave Spring a clean shot at registering the `@ControllerAdvice` on my validation handler.